# Variable based tables

Tags: php, mysql, database

Is it possible to create a variable influenced table?

Like instead of creating a standard table. Can you let users create a custom table. Like on sign up can I do a `CREATE TABLE` under a database and the table's name is influenced by a PHP variable? And the same thing for the fields in the table?

For example, `$username.table` for tables and `$username_field` for fields in the table?

Comment: You dont want to do this. Re-think your model

Comment: Why? I need user to be able to add fields they need.  Sort of like letting them create an onlin form.

Comment: See my answer...engineering is everything

Comment: People are not trying to be difficult here. :) This is an unspeakably bad idea. Database structures are specifically intended to be solid and predictable and this flies in the face of just about every good database design principle known to man. - Much rather open a new question on how to what you're trying to do by doing this.

Answer (score 3):

> Why? I need user to be able to add fields they need. Sort of like letting them create an onlin form

Then you need to engineer your database to allow for this. Not be lazy and create tables for form fields. Not only is this a security risk, it will never scale well. Here is a really poor example of how to engineer a table based system to handle dynamic form generation.

```
DROP TABLE "main"."form";
CREATE TABLE "form" (
"id"  INTEGER NOT NULL,
"name"  TEXT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY ("id")
);
DROP TABLE "main"."form_field";
CREATE TABLE "form_field" (
"form"  INTEGER NOT NULL,
"id"  INTEGER NOT NULL,
"name"  TEXT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY ("form", "id")
);
```

Hopefully your imagination can take you from here.

Answer (score 2):

It's certainly possible, you just need to write well formed `CREATE TABLE`/`ALTER TABLE` queries.

To give your users the ability to create custom fields does not necessitate custom/dynamically created tables.

Consider instead creating a `Custom_Fields` table that can hold user created fields as rows.
e.g.

```
User Table
| userid | username |

Custom Field Table
| fieldid | userid | field_name | field_value

Get My Custom Fields/Values:
SELECT `field_name`,`field_value` FROM `custom_fields` WHERE `userid`=$myUserId
```

Comment: To give individual users the ability to add fields to thehir account.

Comment: This could be achieved with a `text` type field, which could hold a `json_encode`d array of custom fields=>values. Or more scaleable would be relational tables. **Please** don't give your users the ability to create tables.

Comment: Can you explain the details as to why not? I am very new to this, so don't want to have a crisis at hand!;P

Comment: It is an unnecessary headache keeping track of potentially hundreds of custom tables, keeping their names unique, and associating them with their owner. I'll add a better example to my answer

Comment: @AAA: If you are very new to this (and we can tell you are), take the good advice that this is a headache you really want to spare yourself. It *is* a terrible bad idea to let users (USERS!) modify the database structure. Not everything that's technically doable should be done. And besides, it is not even what you need. It's only what you *think* you need - and if you are inexperienced in a field, "what you think you need" should have very low priority, especially if you get strong advice not to do it.

Comment: Well since there is that experience factor, i will be add fields etc for users. so hopefully it works out.

Answer (score 2):

As an option you can create SQLite database for each user and place it in user assigned directory.

Comment: Not a terrible idea...but why not just use 1 sqlite database? :P

Comment: I agree with you, it's much wiser to split form in small fragments like in your example. But it might become handy when you want to isolate each user or application. Plus it's much easier to backup/restore each user.

Comment: Nice retort! I'd have to agree. Obviously, as with anything, it's give and take based on the benefits/cons.

Answer (score 1):

This is not how you're supposed to use databases. If you set up your database like this, you will not be able to make use of all (most) functions your query language.

But to create tables (in mysql what I assume you're using), make use of the CREATE TABLE query.